# Is it possible to show pre-installed android app's activity as Boot LOGO in AOSP?

Tags: android, android-activity, splash-screen, android-source, boot

I am trying to create an AOSP with a boot logo. I also have an android app which is persistant app preinstalled. I want the boot logo to be update anytime later with just an update of the said persistant App. So I thought I would create an activity inside the persistant android app, and there might be a way to call it for the AOSP boot logo.

My logo activity in manifest is

```
<activity
        android:name="com.fivedinside.lifestyle.activities.IntroActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeToolBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.fivedinside.lifestyle.activities.IntroActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Is it possible? If so can anyone please point me to right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The boot animation is shown before the high-level services become available, so you cannot use a normal app for rendering the animation. The code that renders the boot animation can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/cmds/bootanimation).

Specifically, see the [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/cmds/bootanimation/FORMAT.md) description on how to customize the boot animation:

> The system selects a boot animation zipfile from the following locations, in order:
>
> ```
> /system/media/bootanimation-encrypted.zip (if getprop("vold.decrypt") = '1')
> /system/media/bootanimation.zip
> /oem/media/bootanimation.zip
> ```

If you want to have the ability to modify the boot logo without updating the system image, you would have to customize your AOSP to make the boot animation controller look for the `bootanimation.zip` at a custom path, i.e. some path on the `/data` partition that your app can write to. You can then update the boot animation by overwriting the `bootanimation.zip`.

When placing the `bootanimation.zip` on `/data` you have to pay attention to encryption. If you want to use [Full-Disk Encryption](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/full-disk), this approach will not work for the pre-encryption boot animation, as `/data` has not been encrypted yet. If you want to use [File-based Encryption](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/file-based), you have to make sure that the `bootanimation.zip` is exempted from encryption. The precise steps will differ depending on your Android version, refer to the section "Encryption policy" in [this](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/file-based) link.

Further, you might need to adapt the SE Linux policies to allow the boot animation controller to access your custom path.

Comment: Or is there a way, that after the bootlogo is done, the next screen would be the pre-installed apps activity?

Comment: I have not tested it but you can try listening for BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast and open your activity on receiving it.

Comment: Seems there is no way to do that, so using static bootlogo bmp file as the logo instead